# Can we use null inside JSON array?

Tags: json

I've got a JSON object provided by an AJAX request inside my **`asp.net`** application

My sample of code :

```
[2016, 2017, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Please visit [JSON](http://www.json.org/)

You can see right side there is a `null` under `value` section